# Building Custom Bootloaders

Tags: bootloader, avr

Recently I was checking out the Atmel's AVR series and I found the Atmega328PB. I am really familiar with Arduino's environment. So I thought if somehow we could bootloader it with Arduino bootloader. My doubt is how can I make a Arduino bootloader for it.

Comment: From what I remember the 328PB is not that different from the 328P. I wouldn't be surprised is the default uno bootloader would work without modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple sources of ATmega328PB bootloaders based on optiboot:

- https://github.com/watterott/ATmega328PB-Testing
- https://github.com/ElektorLabs/Arduino

I haven't used either.
If you are set on making your own at least they can provide you with a reference.

Comment: Is it fully compatible with Arduino

Comment: Both projects are specifically written for use with the Arduino IDE, though the bootloaders could be used for any purpose you like.